Change Maven Repository Order
Our enterprise team maintains a settings.xml file that defines various repositories that development teams can use with Maven to build their artifacts.
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repo_1</id>
        <name>repo_1</name>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>interval:15</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
        </snapshots>
        <url>https://repo1.url.com</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>repo_2</id>
        <name>repo_2</name>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <url>https://repo2.url.com</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>

Here is my issue: I'd like development teams to phase out the use of repo1 and begin using repo2. However I do not want to force it and would like them to do it over time before I remove repo1 references from the settings.xml file.
Is there a way to do this other than creating separate profiles in the settings.xml file and having the developers deactivate them using the mvn -P=-profilename command?
I basically need to change the order of the repositories to query repo 2 first instead of visa versa
Tried changing in the order in the pom.xml but to no avail

I do not really understand the problem. Just put all necessary artifacts into repo2 and then remove repo1 from the settings.xml.

All artifacts are in repo2 already. Repo2 is managed by a different vendor to repo1 so different credentials required etc. It's a number of different teams with hundreds of Jenkins jobs so just removing repo1 from the settings.xml is too risky

What kind of risk are you talking about? What kind of error do you expect?

Repo1 and repo2 should be identical but there is no guarantee. A gradual transition was agreed instead of a big bang approach! Is there any way to alter the repository order other than using profiles?

How would this "gradual transition" work? Do you want to check all log files of all teams if some artifact is downloaded from repo1?

Gradual transition would be teams moving off using repo1 and pulling instead from repo2 over a given time period. The onus would be on each team to check that the jobs they are responsible for are no longer pulling anything from repo1. A quick search of their Jenkins logs for repo1 and they'd know if this was the case

Make repository 1 much slower than repository 2. Announce it widely. Keep making it slower and slower until you phase it out.

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen it's how to phase it out is the problem. I'd like teams to have the option of continuing to use repo1 until they want to switch to repo2. Ideally by them updating their pom.xml files as all teams will be using the same settings.xml file

@jjcie If you make it desirable for them to switch, they will.  Right now you are just being an annoyance for real work, plus there is no guarantee that it will work after the switch as you explicitly do not guarantee the files will be there.

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen they have no choice. They have to switch. Repo1 is being decommissioned. I'd been told repo1 and repo2 will be a like for like but yes i can not guarantee that

Drum everyone together and make them vote for when to switch and then do it there.
